# Add multiple links to Javascript Iframe popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

how do I add multiple links to this JavaScript, the JavaScript is an Iframe popup, triggered by an external link, I need to add 3 links to trigger 3 different page popups.

I have studied the JavaScript and tried different ways.I searched stack, and found nothing that could provide a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML for using the JavaScript with 1 link.

```js
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('popupiframe').src = "http://example.com";
  document.getElementById('popupdarkbg').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
  };
  return false;
}

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
#popup { display: none; position: fixed; top: 12%; left: 15%; width: 70%; height: 70%; background-color: transparent; z-index: 10; }
#popup iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; }
#popupdarkbg { position: fixed; z-index: 5; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <a href="" id="link">Click me</a><br>
</div>

<div id="popup"><iframe id="popupiframe"></iframe></div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`class`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) to refer multiple elements. Select all the elements with the class with `querySelectorAll()`, then loop through them to attach the event.

You can associate the related link in the *a* element itself using a custom attribute, then on click you can retrieve that and set that as the popup iframe *src*.

Try the following way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.link').forEach(function(lk){
  lk.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('popupiframe').src = this.getAttribute('data-link');
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-link'));
    document.getElementById('popupdarkbg').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
    };
    return false;
  }
});

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("popupdarkbg").style.display = "none";
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}
```

```css
#popup { display: none; position: fixed; top: 12%; left: 15%; width: 70%; height: 70%; background-color: transparent; z-index: 10; }
#popup iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0; }
#popupdarkbg { position: fixed; z-index: 5; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); display: none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="" class="link" data-link="http://example.com">Click me</a><br>
  <a href="" class="link" data-link="http://example-2.com">Click me 2</a>
</div>

<div id="popup"><iframe id="popupiframe"></iframe></div>
<div id="popupdarkbg"></div>
```

Comment: But how do I add the second link to open a seperate page from link 1 example.com, to the javascript, for example: document.getElementById('popupiframe').src = "http://example-2.com"; ....for 'Click me 2' link?

Comment: @ChazSteiner, you can associate the related link in the *a* element itself, then on click you can retrieve that and set that as the iframe *src*. I have updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you my friend! Best answer.

Comment: @ChazSteiner, you are most welcome and glad to help:)